# Is it possible to add hidden text to a caption that only appears in the table of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, captions

I want to add additional information about some figures that should only show up in the list of figures. Is this possible?

Comment: I think that's an optional argument to `\caption`.

Comment: `\caption[This bit goes in the listoffigures]{This bit is the caption for figure}`. there's got to be a duplicate around here somewhere....

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the duplicate. But maybe it’s still helpful to have the same question with different words for people who search it here or on Google.

Comment: @mcb: Yes, closing as a duplicate is purely administrative and for housekeeping on the site. Links between these questions are provided (in the question header for the actual duplicate) and in the "Linked" section (right column) for the original source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like `\caption[My LOF entry]{}`